# nginx - ways to lessen number of files on server - 404 works but returns status 404

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

Our site contains hundreds of album files in a directory named /var/www/album/*.php. Each of these album files is named the number of the album so: 245.php, 943.php, 103.php, etc. These album files consist of nothing more than a simple PHP directive to include the album.php script which also lives in /var/www/album/album.php (the meat behind displaying the album).

I would like to somehow eliminate the need to even have these album files in the directory so my thought was to configure nginx to serve up a custom 404 page if a requested page was not found. In the 404 page (custom_404.php) I have some php code which strips the _SERVER['document_uri'], checks the database to see if it is an album and if it is, the custom_404.php includes album.php. If the file requested is truly 404 then custom_404.php displays Page Not Found...

This works fine with the exception of the Status Code: 404 still being returned, however I cant help but think their must be a better way of handling this situation? I would like to stay away from going the album.php?album=245 route! Is this possible with nginx and php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tell nginx to serve index.php when the requested file is not found:

```
try_files $uri /index.php;
```

Then, in index.php, pull the required info out of the URI:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// logic to extract the album etc
```

So (for example) in your browser you hit http://yoursite.com/album/123 and in your index.php you get:

```
$uri = '/album/123';
```

(Then you can delete all the N.php files.)

Comment: Alex, thank you! I am testing right now... Where would the try_files directive go? Before, after the error_page directive? Should their even be an error_page directive? Currently my niginx config looks like:

Comment: server_name this.domain.net;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/albums;
try_files $uri /index.php;
error_page 404 /404.php;

Comment: Got it to work, had to put the try_files directive within the: location ~ \.(php|html)$ { }

Thanks Alex!

Comment: You'll need to handle errors yourself now (in the index.php) since all hits to missing files will now go there. So, you'll have to do something like, "if the URi format doesn't match what I'm expecting, or if the requested album doesn't exist, then issue a 404 header and output an error message".